# How can I pass html tags to xsl template?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

My XML file has html tags inside, built like that:

```
&lt;pre&gt;

 &lt;table border=""&gt;

  &lt;tbody&gt;
   &lt;tr&gt;
    &lt;th&gt;Time&lt;/th&gt;
    &lt;th&gt;Result&lt;/th&gt;
    &lt;th&gt;Test&lt;/th&gt;
    &lt;th&gt;Method&lt;/th&gt;
   &lt;/tr&gt; 
   &lt;tr&gt;
    &lt;td&gt; 6:28:09 PM &lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td bgcolor="#FF0000"&gt; FAIL &lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td width="30%"&gt; TEST &lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td width="70%"&gt; test_method &lt;/td&gt;
   &lt;/tr&gt; 
  &lt;/tbody&gt;
 &lt;/table&gt;
  &lt;/pre&gt;
```

This is table with test report. I' dlike to pass this table to my xsl template and then display it iside my generated file.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$suite/testsuite/tests/command/summaries/report/output" />
```

Bu in my html i see

```
<pre> <table border=""> <tbody> <tr> <th>Time</th> <th>Result</th> <th>Test</th> <th>Method</th> </tr> <tr> <td> 6:28:09 PM </td> <td bgcolor="#FF0000"> FAIL </td> <td width="30%"> TEST </td> <td width="70%"> test_method </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </pre>
```

as text, table is not applied. How can I display my table in newly created html file?

Comment: What XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: I use Java and default Transformer.

Answer (score 0):

If the used XSLT processor supports it then `disable-output-escaping` can help: `<xsl:value-of select="$suite/testsuite/tests/command/summaries/report/output" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`. Do note that Mozilla browsers like Firefox do not support it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this tomorrow. Until today, I've tested this only in Firefox.